# react native modal issue when containing TextInput and Button

Tags: react-native

Steps to replicate:

1) Use React Naitve modal 
2) Modal contains TextInput and a button
3) enter some text in TextInput and click on button
4) on the first click nothing happens. Keywoard just disappears
5) on the second click text is sent back to whoever called this modal.

```
class ReplyModal extends Component <Props, State> {

  state = { modalVisible: false, reply: '' };

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
  } 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: this.props.modalVisible });
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: nextProps.modalVisible });
  }
  onSubmitReply = () => {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: false });
    this.props.onSubmitReply(this.state.reply);
  } 
  render() {
    return (

      <Modal
        animationType={'slide'}
        transparent={true}
        visible={this.state.modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          alert("your data is saved.");
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.modalViewOuter}>
          <View style={styles.modalViewInner}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent:'flex-end' }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })} >
                <MaterialIcons name="close" color="grey" size={25} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>


            <FormInput value={this.state.reply} 
              placeholder="Reply to the comment"
              onChangeText={(reply) => this.setState({ reply })}
            />

            <Button
              backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
              buttonStyle={{ borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0 }}
              title='Submit Reply'
              onPress={this.onSubmitReply}
            />

          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Issue remains true with 1) TextInput or FormInput 2) Button or TouchableOpacity or anything similar.

Edit: The same issue occurs if on android i click back (on the bottom of screen; next to home button). The first time keyboard disappears and the second time clicking on back button -> Modal disappears.

Comment: have you found a solution for this..

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue but it was actually caused by the `<SectionList>`. Adding

```
<SectionList keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"/>
```

fixed my problem

Same thing goes to

`<ScrollView>`, `<FlatList>`

Comment: I tried the same; did not work. I raised an issue a while ago: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15665

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass key `keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’` on `All` scrollview which are in component stack for the screen. In the ancestors/parent of the Modal also.

Like in my case:

```
const CountryModal=(props)=>{
 return(
   <Modal
     visible={props.visible}
     transparent={false}
     {...props}
   >
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’> 
      …
    </ScrollView>
   />
  )
 }
```

In Parent class:
In the parent class where ancestors of modal is there. You need to pass key keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’`.

```
class Parent extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps=‘handled’> // pass ‘handled’ here also
      …
     <CountryModal />  // Its the same modal being used as a component in parent class.
    </ScrollView>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add

```
<SectionList keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"/>
```

in your sectionList/FlatList/ScrollView

Then in child or render item view close your Keyboard like below

```
 onPressListItem = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
}
```

If you navigating to some other screens or dismissing a modal which might contains some animations so pls use code as below for child item click

```
 onPressListItem = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setTimeout(() => {
   // your navigation or any action here
  }, 0);
}
```